# I can't change maximum heap size in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Going to PhpStorm settings and try to change memory settings doesn't effect.
Currently I put 4048M, but it still set at 1024M.

[image]

In `phpstorm64.vmoptions` the following settings:

```
-Xmx4048m
```

Comment: You restarted PS, right? (Save and restart)

Comment: where is it set to `1024`?

Comment: i reinstall and now in works right.

Comment: it was set in current value (which on screenshot) and in bottom right memory usage indicator of phpstorm